# Create component as a library in Angular Nrwl Nx

Tags: angular, components

I'm very new in Angular Nx. I have to create reusable Angular component and store it as a Library according to Nx workspace structure. I can't find appropriate command. I tried create library using:

```
 ng generate lib mylib
```

It creates library as expected, but I want to store there component which can be used later in my apps.

Comment: Please consider using the [nrwl] tag to give your Nx-related questions more visibility

Answer (score 5):

These are two separate actions - you have to generate a lib in order to create the lib in the workspace (and optionally have a module and import it into another module).

After you do this you can create a component inside this lib.

```
ng generate component mycomponent --project=mylib --module=mylib.module.ts --export
```

Note that we are exporting it to use it elsewhere.

Comment: nx.dev is the official documentation. There is also a free book on Nx if you sign up for Nrwl Connect.

Answer (score 0):

you can generate a component in there using:

`ng generate component my-component --project=mylib --module=mylib.module --export`

This command generates a component called `my-component` in your library (called `mylib` in your case), adds its declaration in the library's main module (`mylib.module`) and finally adds `my-component` to the `exports` array of the `mylib.module` so that any consumer can import the component and use it as desired.

Here's a nice video demonstrating just how to do that:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dji9lNHVj6k